# Is it possible to separate the name from the year and page using any of the \cite commands?

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to produce the following output using any of the \cite commands using biblatex (biblatex-chicago using authordate style to be more specific)?

> Doe writes... (2015,123)

I tried with

```
\parencite[writes...][123]{Doe2015}
```

but that gives me the following result:

> Doe (writes... 2015,123)

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Doe2015 ,
author = {Doe, John},
title = {My book},
year = {2015},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

... which as Doe has demonstrated (2015, 123) ...


... which as \textcite[123]{Doe2015} has demonstrated ...


\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have not provided a usable example but from your description doesn't `\parencite[][123]{Doe2015}` do what you want?

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle for your answer, but no, this doesn't do it. It includes the author name in the parentheses. I was thinking of something like you do with \textcite, where the name of the author is also the subject of the sentence and the reference then provided in brackets, just I'm wondering if it's possible to separate the reference from the author name, i.e. a sentence starting with the author name, provided for by the command, then some chunk of text and the reference in parentheses, again provided by the same command, at the end of the sentence. I'll just make a mwe in a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`.  See the first example.
That will however fail if the there are multiple publications from the same author in the same year.  Then one can define a particular citation style `\citelabelyear`.  See the second example.

## Simple approach

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Doe2015 ,
author = {Doe, John},
title = {My book},
year = {2015},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\dots which as Doe has demonstrated (2015, 123) \dots


\dots which as \citeauthor{Doe2015} has demonstrated
(\citeyear[123]{Doe2015}) \dots


\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

## Approach with new cite command

Here `\DeclareCiteCommand` builds up a style based on the `biblatex-chicago` internal macro `cite:labelyear+extrayear`:

[image: Sample cite output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citelabelyear}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Doe2015,
author = {Doe, John},
title = {My book},
year = {2015},
}

@book{Doe2015a ,
author = {Doe, John},
title = {My book},
year = {2015},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\dots which as Doe has demonstrated (2015, 123) \dots


\dots which as \citeauthor{Doe2015} has demonstrated
(\citeyear[123]{Doe2015}) \dots

\dots which as \citeauthor{Doe2015} also showed
(\citelabelyear[123]{Doe2015})

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @andrew very much indeed! This already mostly does it, and has given me some good hints where to look further. Only that, if I understand it correctly, your solution is excluded from the citation tracking, as mentioned in 3.7.5 of the biblatex documentation, I guess I have to add `\citetrackertrue` to your command. And also  I think there's not much point in writing `\citeauthor{Doe2015}`, better to just write `Doe` instead, as that's much shorter and cleaner, `\citelabelyear{Doe2015}` already pulls Doe2015 into the bibliography.

Comment: I think this is controlled by the `citeindex` macro, which I have now added to the code.  Please let me know whether it works or not.